# How to add annotation in each subplot in MATLAB in loop?

Tags: matlab, subplot

I want to add annotation (year) in subplot to identify which subplot belong to which year.

As of now, I am doing the same using `title` but I wish to replace it with annotation placed inside subplots.

How to do it?

```
i=1;
a=5;
step=0;
for year=2002:2013  
if mod(year,4)==0
    jump=366;
else
    jump=365;
end

subplot(4,3,i)
scatter(data_final(step+1:step+jump,11), data_final(step+1:step+jump,12),...
    a, 'filled', 'MarkerEdgeColor','b',...
          'MarkerFaceColor',[0 .7 .7],...
          'LineWidth',0.5)
set(gca, 'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontSize', 12)
xlabel('variable_1') % label x-axis
ylabel('variable_2') % label left y-axis
grid on;    
title(num2str(year));
i=i+1;
step=step+jump;
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `text`?

Comment: No, I have no idea about 'text'. While browsing I found  `annotation` but it's not working in loop. Could you give some link of `text` here for my reference.

Comment: what do you mean by annotation didn't work in for-Loops? did you use `hold on`?

Comment: @Max why would `hold on` do anything to annotations?

Comment: See: [Text Properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html#namevaluepairarguments) or [Annotation Properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html#namevaluepairarguments). You need to specify the `'Parent'` property.

Comment: Thanks all, I can add the annotation. In my problem, Y-axis limits are different for each subplot. If I give some positioning the annotation comes at different places. What to do, if I want to put it on NORTHWEST position of subplot?

Answer (score 0):

How about if you use *legend* command?
replace the line:

> title(num2str(year));

with

> legend(num2str(year));

Comment: I could get the desired positioing of year while using `legend(num2str(year))`. However, it comes with a color code which relates to the variable being plotted. How to get rid of that color code?

Comment: then try this: `text(max(data_final(step+1:step+jump,11))/2,max(data_final(step+1:step+jump,12)),num2str(year));`  you can play with the first 2 parameters to change the location of the text.